# Can't get file_get_contents or cURL to work after trying all known solutions

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to connect via PHP to the smartystreets API (liveaddress) on an IIS web server.  I copied both the file_get_contents and cURL examples from here: [SmartyStreets github PHP examples](https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/tree/master/php).  Neither of them work.  If I paste the URL directly into my browser, it does work.  The file_get_contents example returns:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.qualifiedaddress.com/street-address/?street=817+Quail+Ln.+%2312+bakersfield%2C+ca+93309&auth-token=5Nk1%2FA) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Inetpub\includes\myclass.php on line 28
```

I have confirmed in phpinfo that allow_url_fopen is on.  I've also tried setting a user_agent.  Still, this doesn't work.

The cURL example returns false.

Could this be something with IIS?  Or perhaps due to a firewall setting?  If so, how do I find out what port to open?  Are there any other possibilities?  Thank you!

Comment: I answered my own question below (it was an issue with ssl being used in the api), but Paul answered it better than me.  If you're having a similar problem, you might want to read both to get the full path I took to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Usually it is enough to get `SSL` to work with `cURL` (*it is some kind of min./default/simple/widespread ;) configuration of SSL used for APIs*), but anyway it depends on the provider SSL configuration.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); // OpenSSL issue
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);  // Wildcard certificate
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

If it won't work, try to know smth. about `SSL configuration of your provider` and you will definitely find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

That webservice requires authorization.

See [`curl_setopt` manual](http://php.net/curl_setopt) for details how to pass authentication details.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no authorization other than the unique auth-token I pass it.  There's nothing in the API documentation that I can see about further authorization AND if I paste the exact same URL into a browser, it works fine and brings back the JSON.  If there was further authorization required, why wouldn't it be in the examples?  Am I missing something here?

Comment: copy that url and try to get to it in the browser... it says "401 Authorization Required"...

Comment: Ah, that's because I changed the auth-token.  I didn't think it was a good idea to share it with the Internet ;)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got cURL working.  The issue was that the link is using SSL (the https in the url).  I discovered this by echoing curl_error($ch);  I added this one cURL option and it worked perfectly:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

I'm not sure if the reason file_get_contents didn't work was related to this or not.